# update javascript variable with php result using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I don't know much things about Ajax, but I need to use it briefly in a project to update a javascript Date variable that will contain the server date/time. It's a very basic task, but since my knowledge of Ajax is poor, it seems very complicated to me.

Here's the php script:

```
<?php

echo(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));

?>
```

Is there any way, using Ajax, to update a javascript variable (lets call it serv_date) with the echo result every 0.5 sec for example? 
I insist on the point that I need the variable content to be updated, and not to display the echo result.

Thank you for reading! ^^

Comment: `setInterval(() => { fetch('time.php').then(res => { serv_date = new Date(res); }); }, 500);`

Comment: You do _not_ want to be making a request every 0.5 sec.  Just fetch the time on page load and use that to initialize a client-side timer.

Comment: @PatrickQ is right, if all you need is to get the current time then you can do this easily with just Javascript on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! it's not about displaying time, otherwise that would have been the best solution ^^

Comment: SO is not a substitute for learning the basics, it's not a programming school. You should find an online tutorial on AJAX.

Comment: "it's not about displaying time"  Then what _is_ it about?  Also, a timer doesn't need to _display_ the current time if you don't want it to.

Comment: >Barmar: sorry if my question was too basic, it's my very first post on SO actually ^^' I'll remember that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn more about ajax here - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp , also you can learn abount new "fetch" api here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

The answer to your question is - Yes, you can. 
You should use setInterval js function in your code. You can learn about this here - https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_timing.asp .

Example:

```
var time = null;

setInterval(function () {
  fetch('https://path_to_your_service/method')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (text) {
        time = new Date(text);
    });
}, 500);
```

Also you need to know about CORS headers, they are needed when you want to perform cross-domain requests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that was exactly what I needed ^^!